No data on second axis
I am new here and have a question regarding the y2 axis in the c3 graph.
Namely, the values ​​refer only to y and not also to y2 as I defined in the code.
I enabled y2 and assigned data14: 'y2'
What am I doing wrong?

function parseData(createGraph) {
    Papa.parse("log.csv", {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            createGraph(results.data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.error("Napaka pri nalaganju podatkov:", err);
        }
    });
}
function createGraph(data) {
    //var cas = [];
    var dateTimeLabels = []; 
    var data2 = ["Temperatura CPU"];
    var data10 = ["Temperatura okolica"];
    var data14 = ["Delovanje ventilatorja"];
          
    data = data.filter(row => row.length > 1);
    var totalRows = data.length;
    
    console.log("Skupno število vrstic po filtriranju:", totalRows);
        
    var startIndex = Math.max(0, totalRows -288 ); 

    for (var i = startIndex; i < totalRows; i++) {
        console.log("Vrsta " + i + ": ", data[i]);
        
        var date = data[i][0]; 
        var time = data[i][1];   
         if (time && time.trim()) {
            time = time.trim();
        
                    var formattedDateTime = `${date.split('-').reverse().join('-')}/${time.substring(0, 5)}`;
            dateTimeLabels.push(formattedDateTime); 
                } else {
            console.warn("čas ni definiran ali prazen za vrstico:", data[i]);
        }
        
       
        data2.push(data[i][2] !== undefined ? data[i][2] : null); 
        data10.push(data[i][3] !== undefined ? data[i][3] : null);
        data14.push(data[i][4] !== undefined ? data[i][4] : null); 
       
    }
    
    
    console.log("Oznake za datum in čas:", dateTimeLabels);
    console.log("Temperatura CPU:", data2);
    console.log("Temperatura okolica:", data10);
    console.log("Delovanje ventilatorja (data14):", data14);
    
    
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        size: {
            height: 400, 
            width: window.innerWidth - 100   
        },
        data: {
            x: 'x',
            columns: [
                ['x'].concat(dateTimeLabels),
                data2,
                data10,
                data14              
            ],
            axes: {
                data2: 'y',
                data10: 'y',
                data14: 'y2'
            },
        
            types:{
                data2: 'line',
                data10: 'line',
                data14: 'line'
            }
        },
       
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                tick: {
                rotate: 40, 
                multiline: false,
                culling: {max: 12} 
                    
            },
            label: 'Čas'
        },
        y: {
               
            label: 'Temperatura (°C)',
            tick: {
                    format: d3.format(".1f") 
                }
               
            
        },
        y2: { 
                show: true,  
                label: 'Delovanje ventilatorja', 
                tick: {
                    format: d3.format(".0f"), 
                    values: [0, 10]
                }
              
            }
        },
        
        zoom: {
            enabled: true
        },
        grid: {
            x: { show: true },
            y: { show: true },
            y2: { show: true }
        }
    
    });
    
}


parseData(createGraph);
        

I apologize, my code has Slovenian words
I tried to find the answer online, even with chatgpt, but it didn't work

Possibly the first elements of the data2, data10, data14 arrays needs to be the same as the property names of the data.axes object.

Sorry, I don't understand, I'm just learning, can you please explain to me, show me what you meant?

I believe that the "axes" property names have to be the same as the first element of the associated data.
In other words,  this:
var data2 = ["Temperatura CPU"];

Has to match the property name here:
    data: {
        ...
        axes: {
            "Temperatura CPU": 'y',
            // instead of data2: 'y',
            ...
        },
    
        types:{
            "Temperatura CPU": 'line',
            // here also
            ...
        }

Check this example


function parseData(createGraph) {
    /*
    Papa.parse("log.csv", {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            createGraph(results.data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.error("Napaka pri nalaganju podatkov:", err);
        }
    });
    */
    const fakeData = [
      ['2000-01-01','18:00:00', 1,2,0],
      ['2000-01-02','18:00:00', 11,12,10],
      ['2000-01-03','18:00:00', 5,15,0],
      ['2000-01-04','18:00:00', 11,12,10],
      ['2000-01-05','18:00:00', 10,20,0],
      ['2000-01-06','18:00:00', 11,12,10],
    ];
    
    createGraph(fakeData);
}
function createGraph(data) {
    //var cas = [];
    var dateTimeLabels = []; 
    var data2 = ["Temperatura CPU"];
    var data10 = ["Temperatura okolica"];
    var data14 = ["Delovanje ventilatorja"];
          
    data = data.filter(row => row.length > 1);
    var totalRows = data.length;
    
    //console.log("Skupno število vrstic po filtriranju:", totalRows);
        
    var startIndex = Math.max(0, totalRows -288 ); 

    for (var i = startIndex; i < totalRows; i++) {
        //console.log("Vrsta " + i + ": ", data[i]);
        
        var date = data[i][0]; 
        var time = data[i][1];   
         if (time && time.trim()) {
            time = time.trim();
        
                    var formattedDateTime = `${date.split('-').reverse().join('-')}/${time.substring(0, 5)}`;
            dateTimeLabels.push(formattedDateTime); 
                } else {
            console.warn("čas ni definiran ali prazen za vrstico:", data[i]);
        }
        
       
        data2.push(data[i][2] !== undefined ? data[i][2] : null); 
        data10.push(data[i][3] !== undefined ? data[i][3] : null);
        data14.push(data[i][4] !== undefined ? data[i][4] : null); 
       
    }
    
    
    //console.log("Oznake za datum in čas:", dateTimeLabels);
    //console.log("Temperatura CPU:", data2);
    //console.log("Temperatura okolica:", data10);
    //console.log("Delovanje ventilatorja (data14):", data14);
    
    
    var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        size: {
            height: 400, 
            width: window.innerWidth - 100   
        },
        data: {
            x: 'x',
            columns: [
                ['x'].concat(dateTimeLabels),
                data2,
                data10,
                data14              
            ],
            axes: {
                "Temperatura CPU": 'y',
                "Temperatura okolica": 'y',
                "Delovanje ventilatorja": 'y2'
            },
        
            types:{
                "Temperatura CPU": 'line',
                "Temperatura okolica": 'line',
                "Delovanje ventilatorja": 'line'
            }
        },
       
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category',
                tick: {
                rotate: 40, 
                multiline: false,
                culling: {max: 12} 
                    
            },
            label: 'Čas'
        },
        y: {
               
            label: 'Temperatura (°C)',
            tick: {
                    format: d3.format(".1f") 
                }
               
            
        },
        y2: { 
                show: true,  
                label: 'Delovanje ventilatorja', 
                tick: {
                    format: d3.format(".0f"), 
                    values: [0, 10]
                }
              
            }
        },
        
        zoom: {
            enabled: true
        },
        grid: {
            x: { show: true },
            y: { show: true },
            y2: { show: true }
        }
    
    });
    
}


parseData(createGraph);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>



